# Why does a unit test fail with the MsTest runner but succeeds with the Resharper test runner?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, mstest

When I run following unit test with MsTest runner it fails but when I run it with the Reshaper test runner it succeeds. With MsTest the **resourceSet** variable is null and I have no clue why?

```
[TestMethod]
public void AllCountriesOfTheDatabaseHaveAnEntryInTheGermanResourceFile()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(Countries.ResourceManager);
    var resourceSet = GetResourceSet(Countries.ResourceManager, Language.de);
   // more code...
}

private ResourceSet GetResourceSet(ResourceManager resourceManager, Language language)
{
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language.ToString());
    return resourceManager.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, false);
}
```

Any idea? What can't MsTest runner load the resx file correctly?

Comment: Have you investigated value of `cultureInfo` in both cases to see whether it differs? Possibly see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/930673/3242721) whether it isn't the case.

Comment: Yes the cultureInfo is always correctly set. And I have exactly the same test for French, Spanish and English and it works fine.

Comment: ReSharper by default shadow copies the binaries into different location. See [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing.html) in order to see how to prevent such behaviour. Could you try to disable shadow copying and re-run the test using resharper to see whether it starts to fail in the same fashion as MSTest?

Comment: shadow copies is already disabled